# How to add a number to a concatenative pair of coordinates within a sublist consecutively?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following list of coordinates:

```
coords=[[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], [(7,8),(9,10)], [(11,12),(13,14),(15,16),(17,18)]]
```

Now I to converted it to a following list using the

```
[m for n in coords for m in zip(n, n[1:])]

coords=[((1,2),(3,4)), ((3,4),(5,6)), ((7,8),(9,10)), ((11,12),(13,14)), ((13,14),(15,16)), ((15,16),(17,18))]
```

so now I like to add a constant value (does not matter the value) to the first set (x+a,y+a) coordinates from previous list such as the following:

```
coords=[((1,2),(3,4)), ((3+a,4+a),(5,6)), ((7,8),(9,10)), ((11,12),(13,14)), ((13+a,14+a),(15,16)), ((15+a,16+a),(17,18))]
```

My intention is make the shared coordinates slightly different so that they have not intersected.

Comment: please clarify how do you want to add const, it's not obvious in your example. do you want to add it to second rrepetitive pair of coordinates?

Comment: Hi, yes, to the second repetitive pair. Actually, in each sublist has same length:

Comment: coords=[((1,2),(3,4)), ((3+a,4+a),(5,6)), ((11,22),(33,44)), ((33+a,44+a),(55,66)), ((111,222),(333,444)), ((333+a,4444+a),(555,666))]  by same length I meant this, except I like to add small value to the second repetitive pair both "x" and "y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do it:

```
x = [m if i == 0 else ((m[0][0] + a, m[0][1] + a), m[1]) for n in coords for i, m in enumerate(zip(n, n[1:]))]
```

Explanation:

in `coords` you have items like `((1,2),(3,4)), ((3+a,4+a),(5,6))`, you should add `a` to all first tuples in item except first group

`for i, m in enumerate(zip(n, n[1:]))` returns item in format `index_of_item, item`

`m if i == 0 else ((m[0][0] + a, m[0][1] + a), m[1])`
Don't modify tuple for first element, else add `a` to first tuple of 2

Comment: is it easy to use modify it to exclude the last point in the sublist, similar to first one?

Comment: Try `[m if i in (0, len(n) - 2) else ((m[0][0] + a, m[0][1] + a), m[1]) for n in coords for i, m in enumerate(zip(n, n[1:]))]`

Answer (score 0):

I would have done something like

```
_ = None # temp value 
a = 11111 # the number you want to add
result=[]
for i,j in coords:
  if i == _: # if the past value is the same as the new one
    _i = (i[0]+a,i[1]+a)
    result1.append((_i, j)) # modify the new one
  else:
    result.append((i,j))
  _=j # set the current value to temp
```

So you create a temp variable then compare it with the new one, if the new variable is equal to the new one you add.